# Remove characters after a specific character in column

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file:

```
chr12   121164863   +   NM_000017
chr17   7126029-7126037 +   NM_000018
chr11   108004589-108004593 +   NM_000019
chr12   52306964-52306968   +   NM_000020
```

What I want to do is to remove the characters after the `-` in column 2 for this desired output:

```
chr12   121164863   +   NM_000017
chr17   7126029 +   NM_000018
chr11   108004589   +   NM_000019
chr12   52306964    +   NM_000020
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I was thinking awk or sed, but they have gotten complicated fast.

Comment: Can you have `-` in other columns? If so include that in your sample input/output. Do you care about preserving the white space in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk you can do

```
$ awk '{$2+=0}1' file
chr12 121164863 + NM_000017
chr17 7126029 + NM_000018
chr11 108004589 + NM_000019
chr12 52306964 + NM_000020
```

or if you want it to work for non-numeric data:

```
awk '{split($2,a,/-/);$2=a[1]}1' file
```

Comment: could you explain what the part for numerical values did? does it mean "only values equal or greater than zero in column 2?

Comment: @crazysantaclaus: Adding zero to a string value casts the string to a number, where the number represented starts at the beginning of the string and ends at the first non-numeric character. For example try `awk 'BEGIN{print "123abc" +0}'`

Answer (score 1):

This is easier than you may think:

```
sed -E 's/-\d+//'
```

Assuming you can do PCRE, but otherwise: `sed -E 's/-[0-9]+//'`

Or just use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/-\d+//g'
```

If you really need to match specifically on the second field, and `-` appears elsewhere:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\w+\s+\d+)-\d+/$1/'
```

Comment: `s/-[0-9]+//;` has a useless trailing semi-colon and you'd need to do SOMETHING to make `+` act as a RE metacharacter, either add an arg to sed (`-r` or `-E`) or escape it.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Tend to end up using `perl` for pretty much everything :).

Comment: I haven't figured out a use for perl yet but I've only been programming for 35 years so I'm sure it's right around the corner ;-). I do think your sed solution is probably the best answer, just needs those couple of tweaks I mentioned.

Comment: ... Oh, everything you can do in sed, awk, grep, shell put together, and a few other things like object oriented code, functional programming and multithreading and parallelism. But aside from that, not much.

Comment: I know what it can do I just haven't found a use for it yet (vs doing the specific thing I need in the specific tool created to do that thing). It does seem to be quite popular though so others must be finding uses for it. Part of my hurdle is it's not available on many of the UNIX boxes I use and I don't have permission to install it even if I wanted to so I don't have a huge incentive to look into it more!

Comment: I used to have that problem 15 years ago, but I find it part of a default install on most these days. My major thing it can do that you _can't_ do well in others is XML or JSON.

Comment: GNU awk has an XML parser that works just fine (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawkextlib). I don't really know what JSON is but if it's something there's a need for I'm sure the gawk guys could provide an extension for that too if asked, especially since there's already a soruceforge parser for it.