# Remove specific characters in column

Tags: shell

I have a file:

```
col1    col2    col3
118566815   comp120568_c0_seq1_xn1_una_478__176 176
118588302   100034943_0__140    140
118575711   100079758_0__55 55
118545625   10009810_0__57  57
```

What I want to do is to remove the characters after the __ in column 2 for this desired output:

```
col1    col2    col3
    118566815   comp120568_c0_seq1_xn1_una_478  176
    118588302   100034943_0 140
    118575711   100079758_0 55
    118545625   10009810_0  57
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{split($2,a,/__/);$2=a[1]}1' input
```

Output:

```
col1 col2 col3
118566815 comp120568_c0_seq1_xn1_una_478 176
118588302 100034943_0 140
118575711 100079758_0 55
118545625 10009810_0 57
```

Do search the site before asking a question :) You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034389/remove-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-column).

Comment: Do not answer a question and then imply that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As written, with a double-underscore separating the last group of numbers you wish to remove, you can do it quite simply with `sed` as well:

```
$ sed 's/__[^ \t]*//' file
col1    col2    col3
118566815   comp120568_c0_seq1_xn1_una_478 176
118588302   100034943_0    140
118575711   100079758_0 55
118545625   10009810_0  57
```

**Explanation**

1. `sed 's/find/replace/'` is the general `sed` substitution.
2. `__[^ \t]*` find - two-underscores and all characters *not* a `space` or `tab` that follow.
3. `replace` with nothing.

**note:** this applies only with the *double-underscore* separating the last group of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

The first sub removes double underscores and the following characters
in front of the zero and leaves zero intact. To make it work I have to
indicate which field is concerned.

The second sub starts at the underscores but here we leave a space instead.

```
    awk '{sub(/0__.*/,"0",$2)sub(/__176/," ")}1' file

    col1    col2    col3
    118566815   comp120568_c0_seq1_xn1_una_478  176
    118588302 100034943_0 140
    118575711 100079758_0 55
    118545625 10009810_0 57
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation?